# Hot Object In a Cooler Space

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, convection

How would you calculate the heat given by an object that is hotter than its surroundings? I know there's Newton's Cooling Law, but what about any heat given off by radiation? Are these additive quantities?

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to the calculated load to heat the total area in cubic feet of the space to 72 degrees. Then add the additional heat to overcome heat loss from walls, windows, doors, floors etc. Then minus the heat gain from people, equipment, solar etc. Finally you design for peak condition like the coldest day of the year. As for the fire places 18 sq foot heat source you would convert that to BTUs and compare to your load calculations. Too many missing factors to answer your question directly.

Comment: We've already done the load calculations for the space, that's not the issue. What we want to know is how much additional cooling are we going to need to provide if they operate this fireplace during the middle of the summer.

Comment: Again its just a matter of balancing the loads. The simplest answer would be to add additional cooling in BTUs to overcome the additional heat in BTUs. Have you checked the fire place submittal sheets for the BTU and efficiency ratings?

Comment: The fireplace is 120,000 btu maximum. But they have some system that blows air between two panes of glass to dissipate heat before it reaches the glass for it to be cooler to the touch. So, what it comes down to is how much heat is given off of a 130 - 170 degree object (temperature of the glass given by manufacturer) in a 72 degree space.

Comment: The amount of heat the fireplace puts off should be the same no matter what the room temp is.Your Ac will need to overcome the additional load if you want to maintain design temp on the hottest day of the year. If you systems capacity was designed marginally then you will need to add the additional cooling in BTUs compared.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Newton's cooling Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling) to calculate heat transfer:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=hA(T-T_0)$$
where:

- $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ is the heat transferred from the glass to the room.
- $A$ is the total surface area of the glass.
- $T$ and $T_0$ are the temperatures of the glass and the room respectively.

$h$ is the overall heat transfer coefficient and can be found on various engineering sites, for various materials and temperature ranges.

Make sure your calculation is dimensionally consistent (use compatible measuring units).

Comment: That's what I was thinking to use as well. I found a list of various overall heat transfer coefficients on Engineering Toolbox that has h as .1761 - .3522 Btu/(ft2 h F). So, we'd be looking at a worst case of about 650 Btu/h? What about radiant heat given off by the glass? How do you factor that in?

Comment: @MichaelDouglass: already factored in! That's why it's called *overall* heat transfer coefficient.

Comment: But if I do just radiation, using 
q = ε σ (Th^4 – Tc^4) Ac 
where: 
ε = emissivity = .92-.94 for smooth glass
σ = Stefan-Boltzmann constant =  0.1714 10-8 ( Btu/(h ft2 oR4) )
Th = hot body absolute temperature (R) 
Tc = cold surroundings absolute temperature (R) 
Ac = area of the object (ft2)

I get a heat transfer of 2243 btu/h. Am I doing something wrong somewhere?